# iOS Take a picture and save in app

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an iOS app. Users could take a picture with the camera, and this picture should be displayed and saved in my app. Even if the app restarts. I have the following code for taking a picture:

```
- (void)takePictureFromCamera {

     if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
         UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
         imagePicker.delegate = self;
         imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
         imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
         imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
         [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
         _newMedia = YES;   
    }      
}
```

And this method for saving the picture to the camera roll:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

     if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
         UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

         if (_newMedia) {
             UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                       self,
                                       @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
          }
     }         
}
```

How could I save the picture in my app, and if the app restarts, show directly the early taken pictures in a grid or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

**Helper Method**

```
-(NSURL *)getDocumentsPathURL
{
    //document directory of app
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                  inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                         appropriateForURL:nil
                                                    create:YES
                                                     error:nil];
}
```

---

**Your `UIImagePickerController` delegate method:**

```
#define k_IMAGE_NAME @"DefaultImage.png"

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        //append filename to document directory url
        NSURL *urlSave = [[self getDocumentsPathURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:k_IMAGE_NAME];

        //do something to previously taken image (in this case: delete it)
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:urlSave.path]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:urlSave.path error:nil];
        }

        //save image to document directory
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:urlSave.path atomically:YES];

        //optional: save image to photo library
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

---

**Way to load image (when app starts or whenever you want)**

```
-(void)loadDefaultImage
{
    NSURL *urlImage = [[self getDocumentsPathURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:k_IMAGE_NAME];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:urlImage.path]) {
        NSData *dataFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:urlImage.path];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFile];

        [imageView setImage:image];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Image not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With this methods I can save one picture to my app with the name defailtImage.png. But I want to save multiple images. I want to create my own camera roll. Than, a user select some pictures en load them up to my server.

Comment: @MartenBiesheuvel : dude... that's not in the scope of your question. Also... what you expect now will be easily twice as much code as this. **Plus...** you know your view hierarchy best. Post a new question and show what you have and what you expect

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

```
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(your_image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Your code become:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

     if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
         UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

          [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
     }         
}
```

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand your second question about display of last taken photo if app is restarted

Answer (score 0):

You can save your image in the apps document directory

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
        {

            UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            if(image)
            {
                NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"anyName.png"];
                [image writeFileToPath : filePath];
            }


        }

    }


    For retrieving the file you can use

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```